# The data provided for 'dest_addr_long' was not 8 bytes long

Tags: python, pyserial, xbee

My script is monitoring changes to the state of my remote xbee. To do this I need to send the destination long address to the router which I get from the coordinator. It all works well if I explicitly type in the destination long address like this:

```
addr = '\x00\x13\xA2\x00@\n!\x1C'    
xbee.remote_at(dest_addr_long=addr, command=mycommand, frame_id='\x01')
```

and it gives me the desired data output which is

{'status': '\x00', 'source_addr': '\x7fD', 'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\n!\x1c', 'frame_id': '\x01', 'command': 'D0', 'parameter': '\x05', 'id': 'remote_at_response'}

from which I can read the parameter to determine the state of the xbee.

The problem I am having is that I don't know the addr up front. I get it when I run this command

```
mysourceaddrlong = repr(data['source_addr_long'])[1:-1] 
addr = "\\".join([(i[0]+i[1:].upper()) for i in mysourceaddrlong.split('\\') if i])
addr = addr[1:] #remove the x in front
addr = r"\x"+addr #add \x to the front and save it as a raw string
print "Formatted addr: %s" % addr
```

Which outputs:

Formatted addr: \x00\x13\xA2\x00@\n!\x1C
This formatted addr appears to me to be exactly the same, but it does not work when I run my at command like this:

```
xbee.remote_at(dest_addr_long=addr, command=mycommand, frame_id='\x01')
```

I get an error saying

ValueError: The data provided for 'dest_addr_long' was not 8 bytes long

I've included the entire script below:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import serial
import time
from xbee import XBee

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
xbee = XBee(ser)

def print_data(data):
    print data
    mycommand = data['command']
    mysourceaddrlong = repr(data['source_addr_long'])[1:-1] 
    addr = "\\".join([(i[0]+i[1:].upper()) for i in mysourceaddrlong.split('\\') if i])
    print "incorrectly formatted addr: %s" % addr 
    addr = addr[1:] #remove the x in front
    addr = r"\x"+addr #add \x to the front and save it as a raw string
    print "formatted addr: %s" % addr
    try:
        xbee.remote_at(dest_addr_long=addr, command=mycommand, frame_id='\x01')
        response = xbee.wait_read_frame()
        myhexparameter = response['parameter'] 
        myparameter =  ord (myhexparameter)
        if myparameter == 4:
            print "Which means pin %s is OFF" % mycommand
        if myparameter == 5:
            print "Which means pin %s is ON" % mycommand
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

xbee = XBee(ser, callback=print_data)

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(0.001)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

xbee.halt()
ser.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`formatted_addr` (my name for the `addr` you compute in your second snippet) only **appears** to be the same as `addr` (as you set it in the first snippet) because you're passing both through the wringer of `__str__` (indirectly via `print`) which strives for aesthetically nice output at the cost of possible ambiguity.  Try instead:

```
print(repr(addr))
```

vs

```
print(repr(formatted_addr))
```

and you'll see the differences -- all those backslash characters are actually in the `formatted_addr` string (and get doubled in `repr`) while they aren't in `addr` (they're only displayed as part of escape sequences).

I can't repro the issue myself as I don't have access to your setup, but I suspect

```
actual_addr = data['source_addr_long']
```

is actually what you want, without all the string processing gyrations around it.  Try

```
print(repr(actual_addr))
```

and unless the problem is fixed tell us what exactly you see from these three `print(repr(...))` and I bet it will be easy to fix any discrepancy that might remain.

Comment: print(repr(addr)) gives me 'x00\\x13\\xA2\\x00@\\n!\\x1C' and print(repr(formatted_addr)) gives me '\\x00\\x13\\xA2\\x00@\\n!\\x1C', but even with the double backslashes (which I believe are not really there, they're only displayed), the now formatted address is still not considered to be 8 bytes long. I seem to have landed in backslash hell.

Comment: Thanks Alex, you solved it. Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees - and now the script is 5 lines shorter too.